# Spring Tools Suite do not show Apache Tomcat in New Server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat9

When I try to create a new Server Instance in Spring Tools Suite Version: 4.0.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201809220817

The option do not show Apache Tomcat options, as in previous versions.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the "JST Server Adapters Extensions" feature installed from Eclipse's Web Tools Platform? That's what usually provides it.

Comment: Thanks @nitind that s soled the problem it was not installed by defualt in new versions

Answer (score 0):

In order to show Apache Tomcat in New Servers, it must be installed the JST Server Adapters Extensions: 
Help - 
Install new software -
Adding 2018-09 - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-09

Expanding 
  + Web, XML Java ...
     +  JST Server Adapters Extensions